# How to pass in multiple arguments in Java Lambda BiFunctions using Async?

Tags: java, asynchronous, lambda, playframework, completable-future

I'm working with a PlayFramework example but I'm having trouble with the asynchronous calls. The function thenCombineAsync seems to only take in a BiFunction. I'd like to pass in multiple arguments to my render function (such as vendors) but I'm not sure how to add more.

```
return entryRepository.lookup(id).thenCombineAsync(vendorsFuture(entryOptional, vendors) -> {
// This is the HTTP rendering thread context
Entry c = entryOptional.get();
Form<Entry> entryForm = formFactory.form(Entry.class).fill(c);
return ok(views.html.editForm.render(id, entryForm, vendors));
}, httpExecutionContext.current());
```

Comment: if you want to collect results of multiple async calls, you can use `CompletableFuture::allOf` function.

Comment: It seems the code is missing a comma after `vendorsFuture` here. However, even with that, I don't see where there would be more than 2 arguments. `thenCombineAsync()` combines 2 `CompletionStages`, and thus passes their 2 results to the provided `BiFunction`. It wouldn't make sense to have more than 2 arguments, except when you want to combine more than 2 stages – which is not possible with a single `thenCombine()` call. `allOf` might be a better fit then, as suggested by @Alexei.